# Как добавить UICollectionView после прокрутки UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Как добавить `UICollectionView` после прокрутки `UITableView`? Использовать свойство `tableFooterView` не вариант. Есть ли какие-либо способы сделать это? Я просто хочу чтобы после прокрутки всего контента `UITableView`, я мог дальше прокручивать контент `UICollectionView`, но при этом `UITableView` уже должен скрыться. Пример: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rnRI.png

Comment: Если использовать UITableView не принципиально, то можно разделить UICollectionView на 2 секции и каждую секцию застилизовать по своему (первую с одной ячейкой в ряд, а вторую с двумя).

Comment: Но неужели для такой просто задачи нужны такие костыли?) Разве нет простого решения? Вставлял UITableView и UICollectionView в UIView, а его в свою очередь к UIScrollView. Но там возникает проблема со скроллом. Нужно что бы это было так, будто UICollectionView есть продолжение UITableView

Comment: Тогда просто в ячейку UICollectionView встройте UITableView и все. То как вы хотите это реализовать сделать сложно и так обычно не делают.

Comment: Как раз помещение UITableView на UIScrollView и подобное - не очень хорошая практика. UICollectionView очень гибкий инструмент и в нем можно отобразить что угодно и как угодно